# Image gets rotate though it is straight while selecting image from gallery

Tags: java, android, image, rotation, exif

I am selecting an image from gallery and showing it on a image view. Image is getting selected, but on samsung phones it has issue of rotating the image so to solve that I am checking the if the image is rotated or not and if rotated make it straight with the suitable angle.

But this is not working for some images. Some images I can see straight, but some images if they are straight then also they are getting rotate.

```
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,512,512, true);

    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, bytes);
    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    loadImageFromFile(destination.getAbsolutePath());

}



public void loadImageFromFile(String imageFile){

    try {
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(imageFile);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile);

        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
            default:
                rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
                break;
        }

        if(rotatedBitmap != null)
        {
            profile_image.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
            selectedBitmap = rotatedBitmap;

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); //replace 100 with desired quality percentage.
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp",null, getCacheDir());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                fos.write(byteArray);

                mProfileImage = tempFile;
        }

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      //  UiUtils.showAlert(getString(R.string.error),NewGroupAcvitity.this);
    }
}

public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix,
            true);
}
```

Rotated bitmap I am getting as null from exif interface still Image which is on image view is rotated.

What's going wrong here? Can anyone help please? Thank you..

Comment: are you facing this problem with all the images, like from camera, net downloaded images, wallpapers etc. or only the images from camera?

Comment: yes with all images not only camera. @AshwaniKumar

Comment: I had the exact same problem and I used the exact same technique to change orientation and it resolved my problem. This issue arises because generally phone's camera save orientation details in exif. You should not face this issue with normal non-camera images. I guess you are unnecessarily rotating non-camera images which does not have any exif information. And that is what creating the problem.

Comment: then how to solve this? @AshwaniKumar

Comment: because if I dont use exif it gives rotating problems on samsung devices. @AshwaniKumar

Comment: hello as I did debug I found that rotated image I get is null still the image applied to image view is rotated. @AshwaniKumar

Comment: that might be because u need to add rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
                break; in case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127716/discussion-between-ashwani-kumar-and-sid).